# Custom sqlalchemy Query, Add filter criterion without the model_name similar to how filter_by accepts kwargs

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Have a use case where i am adding some filters based on RequestContext
The idea is to add this filter in all the queries that are made using sqlalchemy.orm.query

This is what i did

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Query
import copy

# get_permission_field_filters() => {'org_id': 'org001abc'}

class CustomQuery(Query):

    def filter_by(self, **kwargs):
        filters_dict = copy.deepcopy(kwargs)
        permission_filters_dict = get_permission_field_filters()
        filters_dict.update(permission_filters_dict)

        return super().filter_by(**filters_dict)
```

^the above code block works just fine. The issue comes when i want to do something similar for `filter`

```
    def filter(self, *criterion):
        filter_criterion = some_func(criterion, get_permission_field_filters())
        return super().filter(*filter_criterion)
```

since `filter` works with reference to proper `model.column` only there is no straight forward way to do this. Also i cannot call `filter_by` from here because internally it calls `filter` so it ends up in a infinite loop.

I need something similar to `filter_by` but which spits out `criterion` instead of calling `filter` underneath. and a check is also needed to apply the filter if the column exists.

Answer (score 0):

`.filter()` requires a reference to the model's column attribute, so we can use [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) to obtain it.  Something like this ought to work:

```py
critera = {'col1': 'foo', 'col2': 42}
filters = [getattr(MyModel, name) == value for (name, value) in criteria.items()]
query = session.query(MyModel).filter(*filters)
```